# Asp.net Forms Does not Match any rule defined in global.asax?

Tags: url-rewriting, routes

I have a rule:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("routenamea", "{brandname}-prices/", "page.aspx")
```

in `global.asax` and the link `/dell-prices`.

However, the rule doesn't match and links redirectly to the home page. What is the problem please?

Comment: i dont know why rule doest not match...